# Append single item to list in linq statement

Tags: c#, .net

Out of curiosity, I'd like to add an element to an enumerable from within a linq flow, without exiting the flow or casting the single element to an array.

So instead of this:

```
myEntity.SelectMany(e => e.SubEntities.Concat(new []{e})).yadayadayada
```

I want a different command where I wouldn't need to wrap the single element into an array:

```
myEntity.SelectMany(e => e.SubEntities.SomeBuiltInFunc(e)).yadayadayada
```

or

```
myEntity.SelectMany(e => e.SubEntities.ToList().SomeBuiltInFunc(e)).yadayadayada
```

or

```
myEntity.SelectMany(e => SomeBuiltInFunc(e.SubEntities, e).yadayadayada
```

Any construct in the language currently I'm missing that could do this, without creating a new custom function or extension method.

Comment: It's not really strong enough to be an answer, but you can use `Enumerable.Repeat(e, 1)` to technically avoid constructing an array.

Comment: You need to write your own extension method to do that. `Enumerable.Repeat` is less readable, and you need `Concat` too. What's wrong with extension methods, anyway?

Comment: What _specific_ problem are you trying to solve here? The `Concat()` method, or any method that works like `Concat()` is going to require an `IEnumerable` object that represents your `e` value. What do you care whether that object is an array or something else? Why is an array so bad? It's hard enough to understand what problem you're actually trying to solve, and lacking a good [mcve] that clearly illustrates the goal, the question is IMHO beyond unclear.

Comment: I'm trying to find an alternate syntax that doesn't require object creation when appending a single element to an enumerable within a linq statement. Enumerable.Repeat is one that was mentioned that I hadn't thought of, unsure if it's more or less efficient than creating an anonymous array object. Was wondering if there's some other built in construct that would allow me to do it that I haven't seen yet. That's all. Concat solves my problem, this is a question out of curiosity.

Comment: My Rx is to read this: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/

Answer (score 0):

What about the [`Append()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=net-5.0) method?

```
myEntities.SelectMany(e => e.SubEntities.Append(e)).yadayadayada
```

It works pretty much like `.Concat()` but for a single object.

Of course this requires `myEntities` to have the same type as `SubEntities` to avoid casting.

Here is a simple example using `int`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var enumerable = GetNumbers();
    enumerable = enumerable.Append(5);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", enumerable)); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
}

private static IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
{
    yield return 0;
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
    yield return 4;
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wKN8Yh

Comment: I'm looking for an alternate to extension methods

Comment: @user433342 hmm, I'm afraid there is no such thing. Using the built-in methods, using the `Concat()` like you did is indeed the only solution as far as I know. Why do you need an alternate to extensions? Is it just for the sake of curiosity or do you have another kind of problem? Maybe we could help if that was the case.

Comment: Nope just curiosity, haven't had a chance to go through the patent full c# reference

Comment: @user433342 I understand. Please, take note `concat` **won't** add any items to your original list. For example, if you create one `List` with 5 items and another with 3, then you use something like `foreach(var a in list1.Concat(list2))`, it will iterate 8 times, but in the end `list1` will still have 5 items. Now, if you can *recreate* a list with 8 items by calling `ToList()`, which is not the same as **adding**. I thought you'd like to know this, since you seem to be studying/learning (like me).

Comment: Instead of converting to a `List`, one might use an iterator method and `yield return` to first iterate over the original list, then the appended item(s). It's a bit more code, but if one is to write such an extension method anyway, it'd better be clean :-)

Comment: @Mike I edited my answer (after 3 years lol), I guess this makes more sense now.